# Database class method syntax

Tags: apex

Based on salesforce documentation, second parameter in dml method is optional and default is false. 
Like: update(recordsToUpdate, allOrNone)
But it seems to be incorrect, whenever i am updating any list and not giving second parameter, while updating if any one record is failed then all records present in the list are getting failed.
I have to explicitly give false as second parameter, then only it is updating all other records. 
Am i the only one who is facing this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default is `true` (all fail if one fails)

This means that if you specify false, a failure will not abort the transaction.

> The optional allOrNone parameter specifies whether the operation allows partial success. If you specify false for this parameter and a record fails, the remainder of the DML operation can still succeed. This method returns a result object that can be used to verify which records succeeded, which failed, and why.

Source [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_update_2)

Comment: That means salesforce documentations are incorrect. Thanks for your answer.